# "A perverse sheaf is an object in the derived category of sheaves with a constructible cohomology" does this imply it is a *complex of sheaves*?

Tags: category-theory

I compared 3 resources this week defining a perverse sheaf... one site is ncatlab.org, one site is an american math-society article and the other's a wiki page at wikipedia. So then to my knowledge it's an object that is in the 'bounded constructible chain of sheaves' category.

I don't get why just because it is a complex of sheaves- it's not a sheaf; according to the [ncatlab.org entry for perverse sheaves](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/perverse+sheaf), my best guess so far is that it wouldn't yet have been assigned to a topological space.

Comment: I think you're trying to extract mathematical content from a statement where there is none, or at least nothing deep. This is on the same level as "a red panda is not a panda" or "a water lily is not a lily".

Comment: What little I remember from my distant exposure to derived categories is that it might be more appropriate to call it *an equivalence class of complexes of sheaves*, but I'm grasping for straws here.